# Upload GIT Repo through SSH

Tags: git, repository

Ok so i've not really used git to upload to the server before and i've been just manually uploading my application which is really inconvenient.
I have my local git repo with the correct commits and that's all I have done.

My app where the git should push to is at: `/home/(user)/webapps/(app)/app` and I'm having trouble pushing to this.

My remote origin is set to this: `(user)@webxx.webfaction.com/home/(user)/webapps/(app)/app`

This is what I get when I try and use `git push origin master`

Counting object

```
s: 84, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (77/77), done.
Writing objects: 100% (84/84), 1.37 MiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 84 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
To (user)@webxx.webfaction.com:/home/(user)/webapps/(app)/app/.git/
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

That looks like it worked to me but it hasn't uploaded anything

Current Error:

```
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 207 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing to url `ssh://(user)@webxx.webfaction.com/home/(user)/webapps/(app)/app`, change the url to

```
ssh://(user)@webxx.webfaction.com:/home/(user)/webapps/(app)/app
```

Note that I have added a `:` to separate the url from the directory path

This should work (I've tried it), if it doesn't then let me know what error message you get.

Comment: @CallumBonnyman Do you have ssh setup all right? can you ssh into the server using `ssh (user)@webxx.webfaction.com`?

Comment: I have a session open and at the directory, would it be easier to just remove everything from there and use a fresh commit? I'm not sure how to set it all up

Comment: I took the `:` out of the url and it works but says there is no remote git. What would i need to do there? Maybe just? `git init`

Comment: @CallumBonnyman On your server, can you go to `/home/(user)/webapps/(app)/app` and do a `git checkout master`? From the push message, it seems you have pushed changes to a new branch master, and you have some other branch checked out.

If that doesn't work, post the output of `git status` from within that directory.